# Passing JSON array to Java Springs controller

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass this JSON to a Springs Controller:

```
{"orderList":["IS_cb-A1-3","IS_cb-A1-4","IS_cb-A1-1","IS_cb-A1-2","IS_cb-A1-3"]}
```

Here is the method declaration:

```
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse orderCertificates(@ModelAttribute CertificateRequest certificateOrder, BindingResult result )
```

And here is the bean:

```
public class CertificateRequest {
private String[] orderList = null;
private List<String> mbsResponse = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public String[] getOrderList() {
    return orderList;
}

public void setOrderList(String[] orderList) {
    this.orderList = orderList;
}

public List<String> getMbsResponse() {
    return mbsResponse;
}

public void setMbsResponse(List<String> mbsResponse) {
    this.mbsResponse = mbsResponse;
}
}
```

I don't know how to build this bean (which doesn't work) so that I can get to this array. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This signature of the Request mapped method(in 3.1 Spring MVC) should work for you:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cert", consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody CertificateRequest orderCertificates(@RequestBody CertificateRequest certificateOrder){
//
}
```

I have tagged CertificateRequest with `@RequestBody` and removed `BindingResult`.

Update: Posting code, this is how my method looks  -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cert", consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody CertificateRequest orderCertificates(@RequestBody CertificateRequest certificateOrder){
    System.out.println(certificateOrder);
    return certificateOrder;
}
```

and in the http request, I have explicitly set the Content-Type to "application/json"

Comment: When orderList is a String: no problem. It needs to be an Array, which is when it stops working.

Comment: Yes, it works as an array also, in my machine this is the string printed in the method body:`CertificateRequest [orderList=[IS_cb-A1-3, IS_cb-A1-4, IS_cb-A1-1, IS_cb-A1-2, IS_cb-A1-3], mbsResponse=[]]`